# IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm IDE: how to jump right to specific settings screen?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm:

I frequently manage and tweak my live templates and I'm getting very tired of having to navigate each time to the live templates screen.  How can I make a shortcut to instantly jump right to the Live Templates settings screen?  Or any other settings screen for that matter?  Must I use automation with AutoHotKey or is there a better way?

And yes, I am already familiar with the shortcut key to define a ***new*** live template -- that's not what I'm looking for.  I simply want to jump to the settings screen in one keystroke.

---

**UPDATE:**
Going with Chistoph's suggestion, here is my AutoHotKey snippet in case anybody's interested. It's far from perfect; you might need to adjust the timing values for your system:

```
#IfWinActive,.* - WebStorm 201
!t::
    KeyWait, LAlt
    Sleep 600
    Send {LShift}{LShift}
    Sleep 100
    Send Live Templates
    Sleep 300
    Send {Enter}
    return
#IfWinActive  ; turns off context sensitivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method you can use:

Double press shift in your editor, then click on the gear icon for settings. Turn on `Show IDE settings` there.

Afterwards you can double press shift and enter `Live Templates` in the prompt, press `Enter` and you are in the right settings screen.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful and makes automation easy. I posted my accompanying AutoHotKey script above.

Answer (score 2):

As of IntelliJ/WebStorm 2016.2 and earlier, there is no built-in functionality to assign a shortcut to a specific settings screen, but it's fairly trivial to implement that in a third-party plugin.

Note that the Settings dialog remembers the last selected settings page, so if you're working with the same settings page most of the time, you shouldn't need to navigate to it.

Comment: Your suggestion to make a plugin is good but for me it's a little overkill for the request.  In the end I went with the automation approach.